# Dexiejs - Filtering returns single value

Tags: javascript, dexie

My dexiedb structure looks like below.

```
const db = new Dexie('shipment-execution');
db.version(1).stores({
    root: '++id,shipmentid,stopid',
})
```

My IndexedDB will look like below

```
| id| shipmentid| stopid|
| 1 | 6000001   | 10    |
| 2 | 6000001   | 20    |
| 3 | 6000001   | 30    |
| 4 | 6000002   | 10    |
| 5 | 6000002   | 20    |
```

I am trying to get all the data which has shipmentid equal to 6000001. Each time it is returning only one record (the first record ).

```
db.root.where({shipmentid : '6000001'}).toArray().then((d)=>{
    console.log(d);
})
```

output is only fetching the first record

```
| id| shipmentid| stopid|
|  1| 6000001   | 10    |
```

Please let me know, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(async()=>{
  await db.root.where('shipmentid').equals('6000001').toArray().then((d)=>{
    console.log(d);
  })
})();
```

try this and keep in mind shipmentid is string or number